# How can I change the behavior of the ElasticSearch6 Java RestHighLevel client's close() method?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a class `RefreshingClient` which extends ElasticSearch6's Java `RestHighLevelClient` (source code for that [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java)). One of the fields of a `RefreshingClient` object is a `ScheduledExecutorService` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) named `ex`. As part of closing a `RefreshingClient` I would like to close `ex` as well.

Unfortunately, the `close()` [method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L249) of the `RestHighLevelClient` is `final` so it's behavior can't be overridden.

I thought using [this constructor](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L226) of the `RestHighLevelClient` in the constructor of a `RefreshingClient` would allow me to specify custom behavior for `close()`. However, the [consumer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.0.1/org/elasticsearch/common/CheckedConsumer.html) which allows specifying custom behavior has type `CheckedConsumer<RestClient, IOException>`. The type `RestClient` doesn't have a field `ex` so I'm unable to specify that `ex` should be closed using a consumer of that type.

I would like to know how I can ensure that `ex` is closed when I call the `close()` method of a `RefreshingClient` object. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the `ScheduledExecutorService` as a constructor parameter for it to be in scope while creating the `CheckedConsumer`:

```
public class RefreshingClient extends RestHighLevelClient {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ex;

    private static ScheduledExecutorService createExecutorService() {
        return new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1); // depending on your use case
    }

    private static CheckedConsumer<RestClient, IOException> createConsumer(ScheduledExecutorService ex) {
        return restClient -> ex.shutdown();
    }

    private RefreshingClient(ScheduledExecutorService ex, RestClient restClient, List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> namedXContentEntries) {
        super(restClient, createConsumer(ex), namedXContentEntries);
        this.ex = ex;
    }

    public RefreshingClient(RestClient restClient, List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> namedXContentEntries) {
        this(createExecutorService(), restClient, namedXContentEntries);
    }
}
```